# Output dict value on Kivy label.text

Tags: python, label, kivy

First sorry for my bad english.

I´m learning about API´s and I decide to implement a weather API on a very basic KIVY interface. However, Im not able to get the output value of the Dict that contains informations about the weather, as a label text. I think the value is not a string. Would you guys help me?

```
class Tempo_Func(BoxLayout):
    def tempo(self,cidade):
        req=requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' 
        +cidade+ '&appid=mykey')
        self.tempo = json.loads(req.text)
        self.x =(self.tempo['weather'][0]['main'])
class WeatherApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tempo_Func()

if __name__=='__main__':
    WeatherApp().run()
```

## kv

```
<Tempo_Func>:
orientation:'vertical'
padding:10
spacing:10

BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'
    Label:
        text:"Qual sua cidade?"
        size_hint_y:None
    TextInput:
        id:entry


    Button:
        text:'Procurar'
        on_press:root.tempo(entry.text)
    Label:
        text:root.x #I want to show the value of self.x here!!
```

Comment: What is the traceback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your .kv file to this:

```
<Tempo_Func>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 10
    spacing: 10
    Label:
        text: "Qual sua cidade?"
        size_hint_y: None
    TextInput:
        id: entry
    Button:
        text: 'Procurar'
        on_press: root.tempo(entry.text)
    Label:
        text: str(root.x)
```

This seems to work. I get an error because I don't have the API key so you have to check yourself.

Comment: No problem! Mark my answer as an accepted answer so others can see.